# Image won't show when using elem.setAttribute

Tags: javascript, image, aframe

I'm trying to replace a 3D model with a image for an A-Frame project. I was able to remove the model, and replace it with a primitive box, but the image I am trying to use as a texture doesn't load. A box is displayed which is correct, but it displays random colors instead of the image.

**I'm using this example:** https://gamedevacademy.org/aframe-vr-game-development/

**My code:**

```
// Create a new enemy entity.
createEnemy: function (enemyNumber) {
    var enemyId = "enemy" + enemyNumber.toString();
    var newEnemy = document.createElement('a-entity');
    newEnemy.setAttribute('geometry', {
      primitive: 'box',
      height: 1,
      width: 1,
      depth: 0.0001 ,

    });

    newEnemy.setAttribute( 'src' , 'lanternfly.png' );
    newEnemy.setAttribute('shader' , 'flat');
    newEnemy.setAttribute('transparent' , 'true');
    newEnemy.setAttribute('enemy', {'health': 1});
    newEnemy.setAttribute('static-body', '');
    newEnemy.setAttribute('id', enemyId);
    newEnemy.setAttribute('type', 'enemy');
    var position = this.chooseRandomPosition();
    var positionStr = position.x.toString() + ' ' + position.y.toString() + ' ' + position.z.toString();

    newEnemy.setAttribute('position', position);
    var destinationStr = '0 ' + position.y.toString() + ' 0';
    return newEnemy;
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [material component documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/material.html#sidebar). It is:

```
newEnemy.setAttribute('material', {
  shader: 'flat',
  src: 'url(lanternfly.png)'
});
```

[Working glitch example](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lackadaisical-tachometer?path=index.html:14:44)

You have to make sure that you're serving the image file from your web server and that the path / route is correct. Check your browser network panel to make sure the file is fetched.